# How to Make location.href=' ' in <button> tag Work Only If Inputs Are Valid?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on buttons for an questionnaire, which consists of 5 questions. The questions ask about something on a scale of 10 using

I want to print different messages and apply HTML only for certain cases.
1) Let's say the user leaves all questions in the questionnaire blank, and clicks on "Skip" button. This will just direct the user to the next page.

2) If the user answers to some of the questions and clicks on "skip," then I want to print a message asking if the user wants to move on to the next page without submitting the answers. If Yes, it just directs the user to the next page, but if no, I want the user to continue filling up the questionnaire.

Right now I have buttons "Skip" and "Submit" using  and it contains "onclick = "location.href='nextPageExample.html'"> But this will ALWAYS happen, but I need to move the user to the next page only if the user clicks on "yes" without submitting answers. If the user chooses "no," they need to stay on the questionnaire page.

In a nutshell, I have two questions.
1) How can I check if some questions are left blank? I tried id="example" and tried 
    if(document.getElementById("example").checkValidity){
        window.alert("THANKS");
    }else{
        return false;
    } 
but this did not work. It only prints THANKS even when I didn't fill out the question, and sends me to the next page anyway...

2) How can I apply HTML "onclick=location.href='example.html'" only if all the questions are answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a combination of jquery + jquery validation? This should be quite easy. Every page contains a form, you attach the validate handler to it, and if it validates, then set window.location.href="next_page.html"; Otherwise, jquery validation will catch the error. You can even write custom validation functions.

Without seeing your code, it'll be hard for anyone to show you what to write.